# Java generic methods declaration

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to figure out Java generics and I'm having some trouble understanding some methods that are declared in this class:

```
abstract class Trie <T extends HasPoint> {
      abstract <T> Trie insert(T point);
      abstract <T> Trie delete(T point);
}
```

It might not have to do with generics but why is there a need/use for the `Trie` before the method name. Sorry if this is a basic question that has tons of answers here but I haven't found this specific thing.

Comment: And you redefine `<T>` which is a safe way to confuse every other developer.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/methods.html

Comment: Since you don't see what is `trie` in the signature, I feel you want to return a `T` so the method signature is `abstract T insert(T point);`

Comment: Your declaration is incomplete. Return type of these methods loses any generics information that original instance contained. Loot at how `Stream.filter` is defined, that one's much better solution.

Comment: @AxelH, no, right now this looks like an immutable data structure, and `insert` returns a new `Trie` that has a base of original one, but with a new element.

Comment: That code is yours or its provided? Because there's something wrong with that method declarations

Comment: Thanks everyone I got it :) edit:the code is from an API/provided

Answer (score -1):

The basic answer is **yes**, you need *"the Trie before the method name"*. It is the return type. *But* you should use it differently.

---

More explanation:

```
abstract <T> Trie insert(T point);
```

is the very worst of all possible ways to define the method. Proper alternatives are

```
abstract void insert(T point);
```

or

```
abstract Trie<T> insert(T point);
```

The first option does not return anything, it just takes care of inserting.
The second option returns an instance of `Trie<T>` (either `this` or a new instance) to enable you to chain the method calls if necessary.

The original code has multiple issues:

- it redefines `T`
- the return type is raw, loosing its generic information

Answer (score -3):

`Trie` here is the return type of this method
like `abstract boolean insert(T point);` would return boolean

Comment: This is not a link